# Mongoose: Populate multiple fields on the same path

Tags: javascript, mongoose, populate

I have following models: Players, Games and Tournaments
In the Game there are always 2 players and a game can have multiple (0-n) reactions.

games-Model

```
GameSchema = new Schema({
 players: [{player, scorePoints}]
 reactions: [{player, type}]
})
```

tournaments-Model

```
TournamentSchema= new Schema({
 players: [{player, scorePoints}]
 games: [{game}]
})
```

in my "GET" Tournament Request, i want to answer with all user-details and need to populate 2 fields from the same "path":

tournament-service

```
async function getOne(id) {
    let tournament = await Tournament.findById(id)
        .populate({
            path: 'games',
              populate: {
                path:'players.player',
                select: ['username', 'avatar']
              }
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'games',
              populate: {
                path: 'reactions.player',
                select: ['username', 'avatar']
              }
        })
        .exec();

    return tournament;
}
```

The Problem is: since it is the same "Path", it will only populate the last field.
see here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths

e.g.:

```
"games:"[{
  players: [
  {"id": "1", "username": "UserOne"},
  {"id": "2", "username": "UserTwo"}
  ],
  reactions: [
   {"id": 1, "type": "angry"}, 
   {"id": 2, "type": "happy"}
 ]
}, 
{ //* next Game*// }
]
```

How it should be:

```
"games:"[{
  players: [
  {"id": "1", "username": "UserOne"},
  {"id": "2", "username": "UserTwo"}
  ],
  reactions: [
   {"id": 1, "username": "UserOne", "type": "angry"}, 
   {"id": 2, , "username": "UserTwo", "type": "happy"}
 ]
}, 
{ //* next Game*// }
]
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Weeks later, i found a working solution:
you can pass an array with all fields to populate:

```
 path: 'games',
 populate: [{
   path: 'players.player',
   select: ['username', 'rating', 'playedGames', 'avatar1']
  }, {
   path: 'reactions.player',
   select: ['username', 'avatar1']
  }]
```